# Where should I put files that will be used with my project, in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm not sure where exactly to put all the images and DLLs my program will be using.  Do they go in the debug/release folders of my project?  Or do they go in where all the source code is?  Or is it somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DLL files typically go in a lib folder from where they are referenced. Any data you're using typically goes in a folder for access during runtime if it is runtime data. Or you create a rule to copy them to the appropriate folder (Debug or Release) as you build the project.

These sorts of things are always different depending on the project, how many people are developing it and how it is supposed to be deployed.